Pyhon. Конфиг с Discord.py
Помогите сделать конфиг. Суть в том что я сделал бота, мне нужно при вводе команды сохранять значение в файл, чтобы при перезапуске не нужно было снова вводить эти данные, к примеру приведу одну из команд
@bot.command(name="set_report_role") 
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) 
async def set_report_channel(ctx, channel_id: int = None): 
    global roleforreports 
    if channel_id is not None: 
        roleforreports = channel_id 
        await ctx.send(f"Роль для рассмотрения жалоб установлен на <@&{channel_id}>") 
    else: 
        await ctx.send("Вы не указали ID роли. Используйте команду так: `.set_report_role 123456789012345678`")

У меня таких команд достаточно много чтобы вводить их при каждом перезапуске. Я пытался сделать вот так, но у меня не получилось:
import json

settings = {} 
SETTINGS_FILE = "settings.json" 
 
 
idearole = settings.get("idearole") 
 
 
 
try: 
    with open(SETTINGS_FILE, "r") as f: 
        settings = json.load(f) 
except FileNotFoundError: 
    settings = {}

@bot.command(name="set_idea_role") 
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) 
async def set_report_channel(ctx, channel_id: int = None): 
    global idearole 
    if channel_id is not None: 
        idearole = channel_id 
        settings["idearole"] = channel_id 
        with open(SETTINGS_FILE, "w") as f: 
            json.dump(settings, f) 
         
        await ctx.send(f"Роль для рассмотрения идей установлен на <@&{channel_id}>") 
    else: 
        await ctx.send("Вы не указали ID роли. Используйте команду так: `.set_idea_role 123456789012345678`")

Буду очень благодарен если поможете

мне кажется вам лучше завести базу данных, даже простейшую, например sqlite. Хранить команды в конфигах не лучшее решение
